# install php5.3 what is minimum of apache server version?

Tags: php, apache

i installed the following s/w versions
php5.3.0
mysql5.0

now what is minimum requirement of apache server... anybody give right version to suggest me

thanks 
Kumar

Comment: Exactly 5.3.0? Any particular reason to install 5.3.0 specifically, not the latest 5.3.x?

Comment: Possibly Apache 1.3, if you can get the appropriate binaries. Do you really need to use old PHP in old Apache versions?

Comment: Why are you opting for `minimum` of everything? Why not get the latest stable versions

Comment: I bet you could get PHP 4.1 and MySQL 3.2 somewhere if you really tried...

Comment: thanks your comments.. Actually i work with concrete5 cms they are mention system requirement is PHP 5.2.4 or greater (PHP >= 5.3 recommended) , MySQL 5.x or higher. Apache/IIS (Apache recommended) they not mention the apache version , So i need the minimum version.. Right now i choose apache1.3 and above to mention in system requirement?

Comment: @KumarShanmugam the recommendation is **at least** 5.3. This means 5.4 or 5.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimum version of Apache server: 1.3.x ([Windows](http://www.php.net/manual/de/install.windows.apache1.php), [Unix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache.php))

**Recommended version of Apache server: 2.x**  ([Windows](http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.apache2.php), [Unix](http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.unix.apache2.php))

> *"We strongly recommend that users of all
>   earlier versions, including 1.3 family release, upgrade to to the
>   current 2.2 version as soon as possible."* ([source](https://wiki.debian.org/Apache))

Comment: Where are you quoting from? Please attribute your sources properly and use blockquote formatting for quotations.

Comment: @JanDvorak Links and quotation included.

Answer (score 1):

The best version is always the latest version.

This because with every updated version a lot of bugs and security problems are fixed.

Using an outdated version of software is **never** a good idea.

But then, sometimes you come accross poorly written software, or software written 10 years ago that still needs that old buggy software to run on. My advice: don't connect it to the internet.

Do you have to connect it to the itnernet? Look for another job ;)

As DCoder mentioned in the comment. ALWAYS test before deploying an update.

Comment: "a lot of bugs and security problems are fixed" ... and new ones are introduced. Don't blindly update to a new version without testing it first. For example, ImageMagick update from 6.7.7 to 6.7.8 includes a breaking change to the way RGB is handled, which affects almost all newly processed images.

Comment: @DCoder You are correct, one should always test before pushing something to production. But if possible, update to the newest version. I edited my answer with your remark